# Qt for android: project error cannot run target compiler

Tags: android, qt, clang++

I compile for the first time "toutchinteraction.pro" from Qt for android examples.

I installed sdk manager from android studio, all my android setup are well configured except for openssls which is optional (I didn't install it).

When I open the example project from Qt creator, I have the following error: **Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++**

Do you think that the white space inside the path makes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm you that it is the whitespace, I had the same issue, tried everything, and in the end installing the SDK and NDK in a path without whitespace solved the problem